# LiveData and Transformation usage

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I've an Android app with these classes:

- `ListActivity` displays all `Item` objects in a `ListView`
- `DetailActivity` should display all the properties for an object, using another `ListView`
- `Item` is my object which contains `field1`, `field2`, and so on

`ListActivity` passes to `DetailActivity` the `itemId` using an intent's extra parameter when the user click on a `ListActivity` item.

The flow should be:

1. `DetailActivity` instantiate the `DetailViewModel` passing the `itemId`
2. `DetailViewModel` get from the `Repository` the `LiveData<Item>` object identified by the provided `itemId`
3. `DetailViewModel` creates a `List<NameValueBean>` using the `LiveData<Item>` fields (`propertiesList.add(new NameValueBean("field1", item.getField1()); ...`)
4. `DetailActivity` observes the `List<NameValueBean>` and use it to feed the `DetailAdapter` which is the controller of the details `ListView`

The problem is that the `List<NameValueBean>` should be observable, so should be a `LiveData<List<NameValueBean>>`, created each time the `LiveData<Item>` changes.

How can I get that? I think there is a **Transformation** to do but I do not understand how implement it.

Comment: please post code for following class `NameValueBean`, `Item` and `DetailViewModel`. Also add the click listener of list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Transformations.map` function is your best bet to accomplish this.

To give more context, `Transformations.map` will take a `LiveData<T>`, perform a transformation and turn it into a `LiveData<Y>`.

The method takes a `LiveData<T>`, and a lambda who's purpose is to transform the value emitted by the `LiveData`, `T`, into a new value `Y`.

`Transformations.map` will take the value emitted by a given `LiveData<T>` and map and return a `LiveData<Y>`.

Note: This transformation will be done on the main thread.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#map

---

A quick answer:

```
fun getNameValueBeanLiveData(itemId: Int): LiveData<List<NameValueBean> {
    val itemLiveData: LiveData<Item> = repository.getItemLiveData(itemId)
    return Transformations.map(itemLiveData) { item ->
        val nameValueBeanList = mutableListOf<NameValueBean>()
        return nameValueBeanList.apply {
            add("field1", item.field1)
            add("field2", item.field2)
            ...
        }.toList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do that process after observing your `LiveData<Item>` in Activity.